# Windows VS Code cannot load libxcb.dll dependency for cairosvg

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Python script I found on Github in VS Code on Windows and I'm getting the error below.  It looks like this dll is a dependency for cariosvg, but any of the sources I've gotten it from is missing the libxcb.dll.  I think this might be a Linux based dll.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

OSError: cannot load library 'libxcb.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libxcb.dll'

I'm a .NET developer so I'm a little lost.  I think I may have found the source, but not sure how to get a dll out of it.  https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/11.0/x/libxcb.html

I tried using the cario dlls form various sources (GIMP install and GTK package).  I also tried 'pip install libxcb'.